# How to set the value of CURRENT DATE and HOUR in nz datepicker angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8beznk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

***HTML***

```
 <nz-range-picker class="pr-2" [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate" [nzFormat]="dateFormat" [(ngModel)]="dateRange" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></nz-range-picker>
     <nz-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeTime($event)">
              <label nz-radio nzValue="3">Last 3 hours</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="12">Last 12 hours</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="240">Last 10 days</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="744">Last 31 days</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="2232">Last 3 months</label>
            </nz-radio-group>
```

***TS***

```
dateFormat = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
  dateRange: any;
  dateFilter: any;

  disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean => {
    return differenceInCalendarDays(current, new Date()) > 0;
  };

  onChange(date: any) {
    const DATE_FROM = format(new Date(date[0]), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const DATE_TO = format(new Date(date[1]), 'YYYY-MM-DD');

    const FILTER = { 'from': DATE_FROM, 'to': DATE_TO };

    console.log(FILTER);
  }

  onChangeTime(hour: any) {
    const CURR_DATE = format(new Date(), 'MM-DD-YYYY');
    const HOUR = format(subHours(CURR_DATE, hour), 'MM-DD-YYYY');

    const FILTER = { 'hour': hour };

    console.log(FILTER);
    console.log('FROM: ' + CURR_DATE + '| TO: ' + HOUR)
  }
```

What I'm trying to do here is when I click from the radio selection it should set the `CURR_DATE` from START and `HOUR` from END.

How to set a value in datepicker for example. the current date is 06-08-2020 it should display in datepicker `START` then from the radio selection it select the last 3 months then its 03-07-2020 then it should display on the `END`.